# Как обратить функцию хеша?

Tags: алгоритм, математика

Есть входной словарь из 62 букв

```
0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Оно используется для кодирования слов. Допустим есть слово `BOOzE`. Кодировщик шифрует его таким образом

```
"B" (37 индекс словаря) = 37 * (62 в степени 4) = 37 * 14776336 = 546724432
"O" (50) = 50 * (62 в степени 3)
 = 50 * 238328 = 11916400
"O" (50) = 50 * (62 в степени 2)
 = 50 * 3840 = 192200
"z" (35) = 35 * (62 в степени 1)
 = 35 * 62 =  2170
"E" (40) = 40 * (62 в степени 0)
 = 40 * 1 = 40

546724432 + 11916400 + 192200 + 2170 + 40 = 558835242
```

Возможно ли как то обратить этот хеш? Чтобы из числа `558835242` получить слово `BOOzE`

Comment: Делите в цикле число на 62 и берете остатки от деления, которые являются индексами в строке букв. Собственно точно так же как скажем число 123 раскладывается на цифры, в десятичной системе счисления делят на 10 и берут остатки, а тут просто система счисления с основанием 62

Comment: Вообще-то это ничуть не хэш, а просто десятичная запись числа BOOzE в 62-ричной системе счисления.

Comment: @Mike можно поподробнее плиЗ)

Comment: @Harry спасибо за отклик) можно чуть чуть поподробнее? Хотя бы ссылочку

Comment: @Radzhab, вот, например https://ege-study.ru/ege-informatika/sistemy-schisleniya-perevod-iz-odnoj-sistemy-v-druguyu/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да, можно. По сути ваш хэш - это перевод числа в 62-ичной системе счисления в десятичную. Соответственно, обратную операцию сделать несложно.

```
s = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
h = 558835242
res = ''
while h > 0:
    ind = h % 62
    sym = s[ind]
    res = sym + res
    h //= 62
print(res)
```

Comment: h //= 62
 это что за операнд?

Comment: @Radzhab, то же, что и h = h // 62

Comment: @Radzhab Имеется ввиду h=целая_часть(h / 62)

Answer (score 4):

Подробнее - простой перевод чисел в 62-ричную систему счисления и назад. Т.е. каждая строка из соответствующих букв рассматривается как запись в [позиционной системе счисления](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) с основанием 62 и цифрами из вашей строки.

Это - **однозначное** преобразование, так что это никак не хэш.

Ну, а на С++, например, функции туда-назад выглядят [следующим образом](https://ideone.com/RlaVc5):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

const char digs[] = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

unsigned long long code62(const string& ss)
{
    unsigned long long code = 0;
    for(const char * s = ss.c_str(); *s; ++s)
    {
        code = code * 62 + (strchr(digs,*s)-digs); // Номер символа
    }
    return code;
}

string decode62(unsigned long long val)
{
    string res;
    while(val)
    {
        res = digs[val%62] + res;
        val /= 62;
    }
    return res;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    unsigned long long code = code62("BOOzE");
    cout << code << endl;
    cout << decode62(code) << endl;
}
```